# Error handling along with roll back and commit option with error message in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, commit, rollback, error-logging

I have a stored procedure, which has handlers with flag for roll back, how do I get the error message from the handler.

I have declared handlers for various exception along with flag for roll back as shown below.

```
...
BEGIN
DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1051  SET `_rollback` = 1;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 SET `_rollback` = 1;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET `_rollback` = 1;
START TRANSACTION;
......
.....
IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
```

The expected output is error message based on handler.But since it just follows this syntax refered from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/)

DECLARE action HANDLER FOR condition_value statement;

I am unable to get  error message. One way is to write generic error message after the ROLLBACK, but how to get specific message?